# Issue with grid grouping and widgetcolumn in Extjs 6.2.1

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using a grid with grouping feature. I also have a widget column with button as a widget.

Here is the link of fiddle - https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3j2s

When we drag columns then Ext throws an error and it crashes the application. Error is random and it can appear on the first column drag or it also can appear after 5-10 column drag. I also tried the same fiddle with ExtJs 6.5 and there I did not face this issue. It seems this is an issue with older ExtJs versions. Is there any workaround for this or any quick fix? I am also attaching a screenshot of the error in fiddle - [Error screenshot in fiddle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFvGu.png)

Answer (score 0):

I tested your fiddle and I am getting tons of errors. All different. None seems to be happening because of the widgetcolumn though.

The most obvious one was: Drag to a position that is not valid and then drag it again to a valid position ==> Error

Solution: Please update to version 6.7

Comment: Other than upgrading to newer Extjs version, isnt there any override that I can use to avoid these issues? As I mentioned in my question, error is very random and can happen just after the first try or can take many tries to replicate the error. Also there is another issue where hidden bind with widgetcolumn does not work properly. I have updated my fiddle with this case. Just collapse group 2 and then expand. Every button is now hidden. This works fine in Extjs 6.5 or newer.